# Multiple css classes on one element in e4

Tags: java, css, eclipse, rcp, e4

I tried to design some components in a e4 RCP application with css.

One thing I stumbled upon was that when you execute

> ```
> cssEngine.setClassname(composite, "class1");
> cssEngine.setClassname(composite, "class2");
> ```

It seems like composite would not have "class1" anymore but only "class2".

Isn't it possible like on website elements (<a class="class1 class2"></a>) to give one object multiple classes?

Comment: RCP of course - edited that

Comment: Have you tried `cssEngine.setClassname(composite, "class1 class2");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, HTML does support multiple classes. However the e4 `IStylingEngine` and `WidgetElement` classes only seem to support one class.

Update:
Testing this further the CSS class matching code does deal with spaces in the class string so it is possible to specify multiple classes separated by space.

Comment: Indeed the method with using spaces as separator does work. Thank you very much.